react native WebView redirect 302 and get history
I have a couple of questions. How can I retrieve the browsing history from a react-native-webview ? Also, how can I detect a 302 redirect within the react-native-webview ? Any guidance would be helpful.
Thanks
I attempted to retrieve the browsing history in a react-native-webview by using the standard methods available in the react-native-webview API. Additionally, I tried to detect 302 redirects by monitoring the WebView's URL loading process. I expected to obtain a detailed history of the pages visited within the WebView and receive notifications or callbacks whenever a 302 redirect occurred. However, I have not found a solution for these issues yet.
